# Meaning of term transparency in software engineering

Tags: architecture

Quite often I see myself confused when talking about *code transparency*.
What I'm trying to clarify myself are constructs such as:

- This should be **transparent to the user**
- Caching should be **transparent** to the application

Would be great if someone could clarify, with some small pseudo code snippet, what's the actual meaning of such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generally means that it is invisible to the user.  The user can use the application, and not know that a feature exists.

So, for caching to be "transparent", the application should not know that a caching layer exists.  This is most easily exemplified by the opposite, in that a non-transparent caching layer would require the application invoke methods to check/expire caches.

Comment: Does that mean that it is transparent to the user if I have method such as

    @Cacheable("users")
    User getUser(int userId) {

?

Comment: that would transparent to the user, not to the application.  The user does not know that there is a cache in-place.  The application however, does.  The @Cacheable means that it knows that things are getting cached.